Cartoon series in which people use gems or stone to put some kind of beasts out from it
As I remember it was a cartoon anime series which I saw in India around 2010 & 2011.
In this series people used to fight other with some beast which was captured in stone. They don't want the world to know that there are things like this. 
As I remember in episode 1 (not perfect) there was a college student who run to his home then there some strange happen and some Villains arrive (confused) to take his stone which was in his neck like pendant or a beast from stone arrive to tell him truth  when he was with a girl. 
Now all I remember about the pendant is it was his dad pendant who had been died  somehow he gave him pendant. It has a beast in it who protect the boy.  After this boy's journey start and the girl know what is this happening may be she also have some stone beasts. 
After some episodes, he forms an alliance who had powerful stone beast. And at end of episode he came to know that his father collect many of these stone and he fight with some evil people who are now behind his stone beast.
The beast of pendant have name starting from C may be Camereon or Camelon like this similar to these names. This beast was most important best in this show.

I remember that the boy made a alliance of four or five members who later help him fight with evils and they all can control these beasts

Yah may be it was on Cartoon Network , Animax , Disney XD or  Hungama

No Kiba is not for what I m looking for. Thanks for your try. Pls try again and search my show

I'm sure it's not actually Pokemon, as that would seem too obvious, but it definitely sounds like a Pokemon clone.  Is it perchance any of these?  http://www.hardcoregamer.com/2013/08/31/the-top-five-pokemon-impostors/54015/

No it was not game or didn't related to this games.

Could it be Shaman King? The opening scene you describe sounds familiar..

No it is not shaman king.


Could it be Huntik : secrets & seekers

The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit. Season one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind, Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the Huntik team.

